# Is there a way to set the library path through batch?

Tags: java, batch-file

I tried to make a batch starting my .jar so it look´s better. But my .jar needs some native librarys and I don´t know how to set them threw  my start batch.

I already tried to use the `-Djava.library.path=` argument but it didn´t work.

Here is my full code I´ve already tried:

```
java -Djava.library.path=natives-windows\* -cp game.jar;libs\*; net.ss.Game
```

When I start the batch the .jar starts but I get an excpetion that I need the specific native librarys.

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl64 in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:87)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
        at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:39)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:36)
        at net.ss.Game.start(Game.java:40)
        at net.ss.Game.main(Game.java:20)
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

Comment: From the stack trace you posted: `at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)` I assume `Sys.java` is a file you wrote. If it is then post the code for class `org.lwjgl.Sys`.

Comment: ``Sys.java`` is not from me, it´s a library from lwjgl64. My class is ``net.ss.Game.java``.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with LWJGL but I see that the download contains many JAR files and some of those JAR files contain native libraries including DLL files for Windows and SO files for Linux. What platform are you on?

Comment: Did you read the [installation guide](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/1.2.-Install) ?